# tensorboard ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 2)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

Im using jupyter on vast.ai

Im running model and record the logs for tensorboard

```
logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
```

but then when try to visualize the results with

```
%tensorboard --logdir = logs --port=6006
```

i get error:

```
ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 2).
Contents of stderr:
usage: tensorboard [-h] [--helpfull] [--logdir PATH] [--logdir_spec PATH_SPEC]
                   [--host ADDR] [--bind_all] [--port PORT]
                   [--reuse_port BOOL] [--load_fast {false,auto,true}]
                   [--extra_data_server_flags EXTRA_DATA_SERVER_FLAGS]
                   [--grpc_creds_type {local,ssl,ssl_dev}]
                   [--grpc_data_provider PORT] [--purge_orphaned_data BOOL]
                   [--db URI] [--db_import] [--inspect] [--version_tb]
                   [--tag TAG] [--event_file PATH] [--path_prefix PATH]
                   [--window_title TEXT] [--max_reload_threads COUNT]
                   [--reload_interval SECONDS] [--reload_task TYPE]
                   [--reload_multifile BOOL]
                   [--reload_multifile_inactive_secs SECONDS]
                   [--generic_data TYPE]
                   [--samples_per_plugin SAMPLES_PER_PLUGIN]
                   [--detect_file_replacement BOOL]
                   [--whatif-use-unsafe-custom-prediction YOUR_CUSTOM_PREDICT_FUNCTION.py]
                   [--whatif-data-dir PATH]
                   {serve,dev} ...
tensorboard: error: invalid choice: 'logs' (choose from 'serve', 'dev')
```

i try also use

```
from tensorboard import notebook
notebook.list() ## Known TensorBoard instances:
##  - port 6006: logdir logs (started 0:49:56 ago; pid 907)
 ## - port 6006: logdir logs (started 0:22:41 ago; pid 528)
notebook.display(port=6006, height=1000)
```

but get this:[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: try `%tensorboard --logdir=logs --port=6006` without the spaces

Comment: I had tried, but the outcome is the same